# optimize the link between a table use regexp_substr and simple table

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT
    'SA',    v.ctty, v.czta,regexp_substr(    v.currency, '[^, ]+', 1, column_value  ) relac
FROM vcft2b v,(TABLE ( CAST(MULTISET(SELECT level FROM  dual   CONNECT BY level <= length(    regexp_replace(     currency, '[^, ]'  )    ) + 1  ) AS sys.odcinumberlist) ))a
WHERE
    v.repso = 'O'
    AND v.proi = 'N';
```

how can i link between the result of the a to the table vcft2b v?

Comment: Please edit the question, show the DDL of the tables in question, and sample data that shows the relationship

Comment: This query is dealing with a string column `currency` that contains a list of currencies separated by comma. You are interested in the separate currencies, so you split the column values into rows. But if you are interested in the separate currencies in your database, you must not store them as a comma-separated string in the first place, as this violates normalization. The solution is hence not to muddle through in every other query, but fix the data model by having a child table listing the separate currencies in separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly would you "optimize" here?

Query you posted is used to split `currency` column value into rows. `table` is used to avoid duplicates.

As far as I can tell, that's just fine and should work OK.

If you thought of "simplifying" that query with `distinct` and `level` instead of `column_value`

```
SELECT DISTINCT -- distinct here
    'SA',
    v.ctty,
    v.czta,
    regexp_substr(v.currency, '[^, ]+', 1, level) relac --> level instead of column_value
FROM vcft2b v
WHERE v.repso = 'O'
  AND v.proi = 'N'
CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(regexp_replace(currency, '[^, ]')) + 1  )
```

you *could* do it (and query would look simpler), but - performance wise - it'll be much worse. You won't notice any difference on a small table, but as number of rows  raises, performance will suffer.

My suggestion: leave it *as is*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .when I comment out the regular expressions in the Query, I get the results in a few seconds. As Regular Expression is a string search operation, each character in each rows column will be scanned for the regular expression value.

Could you please guide me to more optimise it ?

Comment: On large data sets, regular expressions are slow. See if you can substitute it with SUBSTR + INSTR combination. We could try to do it for you, but it's useless without any sample data.